# Need help with a script that uses passwd and shadow

Tags: linux, authentication, passwd, shadow

I would like assistance with something I have to do.

I need to verify if all users in passwd are also in shadow, if the primary group exists, if the homedir exists and if it belongs to the correct user/group. If something is wrong, it should output it to a new file, called for example "errors".

How can I implement a script that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pwck](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pwck.8.html) is probably what you seek.

> The pwck command verifies the integrity of the users and
> authentication information. It checks that all entries in
> /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow have the proper format and contain
> valid data. The user is prompted to delete entries that are
> improperly formatted or which have other uncorrectable errors.

Similarly, [grpck](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/grpck.8.html) verifies the integrity of the group information files.

> The grpck command verifies the integrity of the groups
> information. It checks that all entries in /etc/group and
> /etc/gshadow have the proper format and contain valid data. The
> user is prompted to delete entries that are improperly formatted
> or which have other uncorrectable errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly what I needed!